# Unable to drag the hierarchy tree in iOS Browser - thejit

Tags: iphone, cordova, ios-simulator, mobile-safari, thejit

Unable to drag the **spacetree** in safari browser on **IPhone simulator**.

I tried below examples on my safari browser in IPhone Simulator.

http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html

http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example2.html

http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example3.html

Please help to perform drag on the hierarchy tree inside the safari browser on IPhone simulator.

**I am using phonegap for my application to implement in IPhone** but this hierarchy tree drag functionality itself not working in IPhone simulator browser since I can't run as mobile app.

Please help via code wise what I needs to change to run this code in Iphone!

Answer (score 2):

There is no **drag** functionality, actually, it is just a **click** functionality. After some tests on the iPhone Safari browser I can report to you that it is working very well - spacing and animations are rendered perfectly.